# Flutter How to pass a parameter (int) to callbacks?

Tags: flutter, dart, callback

How can I pass a parameter wit callback in Flutter?

I have two files **main.dart** and **block.dart**. My goal is to add an int (12 for example) to **myCallback** in **block.dart** to use it in **main.dart** in the function **whatToDo** (instead of `print ('Should receive the Value from myCallback');`)

Here is the code of the **main.dart** File:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'block.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MainBlock(),
    );
  }
}

class MainBlock extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainBlockState createState() => _MainBlockState();
}

class _MainBlockState extends State<MainBlock> {
  void whatToDo() {
    print('Should receive the Value from myCallback');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // print(getraenke.asMap());
    // print(getraenke.asMap().keys);
    // print(getraenke);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        color: Color(0xFF122C39),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Block(
                myCallback: whatToDo,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the Code from **block.dart** with the callback:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Block extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function myCallback;

  Block({this.myCallback});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      color: Color(0xFF722662),
      child: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: myCallback,
          child: Text(
            'Button',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
              fontSize: 22.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way without any advanced topic. Better read some articles about state  management. [Official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MainBlock(),
    );
  }
}

class MainBlock extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainBlockState createState() => _MainBlockState();
}

class _MainBlockState extends State<MainBlock> {
  void whatToDo(int value) {
    print('Should receive the Value from myCallback');
    print(value);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // print(getraenke.asMap());
    // print(getraenke.asMap().keys);
    // print(getraenke);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        color: Color(0xFF122C39),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Block(
                myCallback: whatToDo,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Block extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function(int) myCallback;

  Block({required this.myCallback});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      color: Color(0xFF722662),
      child: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: ()=>myCallback(12),
          child: Text(
            'Button',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
              fontSize: 22.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you for the reading tip on State Management. I've read it all through and I have to get down to learning and understanding it. very interesting and promising.

Answer (score 5):

If I understood it correctly, You want your function to accept a parameter.
do it like this.

```
class Block extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function(int num) myCallback;

  Block({this.myCallback});
```

and when you call it, you provide it with the parameter

```
GestureDetector(
          onTap:()=> myCallback(12),
          child: ...
```

and finally you can access it from your main

```
void whatToDo(int num) {
    print(num);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

in main.dart:

```
  void whatToDo(int value) {
    print('the value is $value');
  }
```

in block.dart:

```
class Block extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueChanged<int> myCallback;

  Block({required this.myCallback});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      color: const Color(0xFF722662),
      child: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => myCallback(100),
          child: const Text(
            'Button',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
              fontSize: 22.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: if you add some explanation you may get more easily upvotes because you increased answer quality.

Answer (score 0):

I add more info to [Ethsan Askari's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69448187/9192954).

You can define your custom callback and reuse it throughout your app.

```
typedef OnWhatToDoCallback = Function(int value);

class Block extends StatefulWidget {
  const Block({
    Key? key,
    required this.onWhatToDo,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final OnWhatToDoCallback onWhatToDo;
  ...
}
```